# how can I create a new Dimension in SSAS using MDX without processing Cube?

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, cube, slicers

I need to create a dimension using another dimension to create some calculated attributes in SSAS to show in excel slicer. But I Don't want to process cube. Only use MDX code to use another dimension and create new dimension to use in slicer.

For example we have a dimension named DimAgeGroup. it has 7 group.

0-10 , 10-20 , ... , 60-70

then i need to create a dimension using mdx to show before 30 and after 30 to show in excel slicer without any cube processing.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you want is 2 new calculated members.And calculated members you can deploy without making the cube unprocessed.

```
CREATE MEMBER [DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[All].[Before 30]
AS
([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[0-10],[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER]) +
([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[0-20],[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER])
,VISIBLE =1;

CREATE MEMBER [DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[All].[After 30]
AS
([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[30-40],[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER])+
([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[40-50],[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER])+
([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[50-60],[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER])+
([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].[60-70],[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER])
,VISIBLE =1;
```

You can deploy either with XMLA or within Visual studio with BIDS Helper (Deploy MDX script feature).

Not so sure about the MDX.. can't test it right now.

Comment: Yes, I do this before. But it has a problem. After I connect to my cube in Excel, Slicer need a Dimension to show it's attributes, after I select DimAgeGroup , i can see 0-10 , ... , 50-60 , before30 , after30
but I want to see only before30,after30, 
Because of this I need a new dimension.

Comment: About your solution we can use 
Aggregate([DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].&[1] : [DimAgeGroup].[AgeGroup].&[5] )

Comment: You could try and add those Calculated members to another Attributes hierarchy and make  the AgeGroup attribute not visible.

Comment: But I should do this in ssas and I need other age groups to use in other slicers.